# iOS folders structure in resources

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview, structure, directory

I want to organize my app with folders . Then I created folders in Resources like : /Resources/Controllers

I put the same namespace, so in other view I can call: new myControllerInFolder() but when I launch, it tell me that it doesn't has reference ? Can you help me please?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just founded it : make your file in **Compile** property